# Maven test: files created of the test arn't created by mvn test, but with normal IntelliJ Testrunne

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I have a project where we write files during the unit tests. They should be written to `target/testData`. This works wonderfull if I run the Tests with the IntelliJ Testrunner. If I run `mvn test` it runs succesfully but it doesn't create the files. Whats wrong?

This is my Surefire config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <myOutDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}</myOutDir>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
        <forkMode>never</forkMode>
        <workingDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The file ist created in following dir:

```
private static final String resultDirName =
    String.format("%s%stestData", System.getProperty("myOutDir"), File.separator);
```

and used like that:

```
resultDir = new File(resultDirName);
if (!resultDir.exists() && !resultDir.isDirectory()) {
    resultDir.mkdir();
}
if (result != null) {
    String name = "someName
    File resultFile = new File(resultDir, name);
    ImageIO.write(result, "JPEG", resultFile);
}
```

Comment: Try printing out `resultDir.getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: Hint: Consider using the members of the newer package [java.nio.file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html).